# TypeError when extending a method from a base class

Tags: python, inheritance, methods

I was trying to test a simple Python inheritance case, but I am having problems understanding the error Python interpreter is spitting out.

```
class Mainclass(object):
    """
     Class to test the inheritance
    """
    def __init__(self,somevalue):
        self.somevalue = somevalue
    def display(self):
        print(self.somevalue)


class Inherited(Mainclass):
    """
    Inherited class from the Main Class
    """
    def display(self):
        print("**********")
        Mainclass.display()
        print("**********")

c = Inherited(100)
c.display()
```

I was just trying to add asterisks to the displayed output in the `Inherited` class, so why it is failing with the following error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 21, in <module>
c.display()
line 17, in display
Mainclass.display()
TypeError: display() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: Well that error looks pretty self-explanatory, doesn't it? You're missing the required argument "self".

Comment: self is supposedly the reference to class instance or the class itself, right? I am confused there

Comment: You can use super().display() instead

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass self from the inherited class's display method to the Mainclass.display() method when you call it. So your code becomes:

```
class Mainclass(object):
  """
   Class to test the inheritance
  """
  def __init__(self,somevalue):
      self.somevalue = somevalue
  def display(self):
      print(self.somevalue)


class Inherited(Mainclass):
  """
  Inherited class from the Main Class
  """
  def display(self):
      print("**********")
      Mainclass.display(self)
      print("**********")

c = Inherited(100)
c.display()
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it, I am confused as to why I would need to pass "self" object to this function given that I am calling this function directly using the Mainclass.display() construct.

Comment: Since you created an instance of Inherited, c.somevalue is where your 100 gets stored. When you call Mainclass.display() and reference self without passing anything, it refers to Mainclass which doesn't have that value stored in it. By passing Inherited's self object through to Mainclass.display() we are telling it to use the scope with somevalue stored in it.

Comment: Thanks, what was I thinking :)

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is to call `super` like this

```
# Python 2.7 using new style classes
class Inherited(Mainclass):
"""
Inherited class from the Main Class
"""
    def display(self):
        print("**********")
        super(Mainclass,self).display(self)
        print("**********")
```

or this way

```
# Python 3.x
class Inherited(Mainclass):
"""
Inherited class from the Main Class
"""
    def display(self):
        print("**********")
        super().display(self)
        print("**********")
```